# Round through error SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found an weird thing in SQL Server 2008 today. I write a `ROUND` function, and I test this randomly.

From 9.50-9.99, this line of code:

```
SELECT ROUND(X.XX, 0);
```

throws this error:

> An error occurred while executing batch.
>   Error message is: Arithmetic Overflow.

but from 9.00-9.49 it is working just fine.

Can anybody please let me know what's wrong with that code?

Comment: Show us the function code.

Comment: @jarlh The code is already there: execute `SELECT ROUND(9.50,0);` in SQL and you get the error.

Comment: Did u tried to enclose value in quotes

Comment: The [**ROUND documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql) also shows this as an example when using `ROUND(748.58, -3)` and explains it as: `Results in an arithmetic overflow, because 748.58 defaults to decimal(5,2), which cannot return 1000.00.` I suppose you could cast within the ROUND similar to this: `SELECT ROUND(cast(748.58 as float),-3);` not sure if that is reliable though.

Answer (score 7):

This is because it is trying to implicitly fit this into a `numeric(3,2)` datatype, which 10.00 will over flow.  You need to cast it to a larger datatype: `select round(cast(9.50 as numeric(4,2)),0)`

You can run this code to see what the implicit datatype & precision is:

```
select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY (cast(9.50 as SQL_VARIANT), 'BaseType'),
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY (cast(9.50 as SQL_VARIANT), 'Precision'),
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY (cast(9.50 as SQL_VARIANT), 'Scale')
```